# Cucumber .Hoook class is throwing errors due to not having an empty constructor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, cucumber

I've been struggling with this issue all the day and no way for solving it.

The thing is that if I put a non-empty constructor (with the context) for the .Hooks class, there is an exception of the kind
*io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: class com.foo.bar.steps.rest.Hooks doesn't have an empty constructor. If you need dependency injection, put cucumber-picocontainer on the classpath*

So, I tried both:  an empty for the Hooks class and inserting cucumber-picocontainer in the class path.

Let's see them separately:

For the empty constructor, what I am doing is:

```
public Hooks() {
    }
```

This makes tests to throw this error:
*java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.foo.bar.utilities.TestContext.getDriverManager()* because "this.testContext" is null

Another approach of the same thing is:

```
        TestContext context = new TestContext();
        this.testContext = context;
    }
```

This causes an error like this:
*io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: class com.foo.bar.steps.rest.Hooks doesn't have an empty constructor. If you need dependency injection, put cucumber-picocontainer on the classpath*

And no tests are executed.

If I put a non empty constructor, like this:

```
public Hooks(TestContext context) {
        testContext = context;
    }
```

I get the *non empty constructor* error,  as above.

Regarding the cucumber-picocontainer on the classpath approach, I have created an environment variable named CLASSPATH and now it looks like this:

```
 % echo $CLASSPATH
/Users/myusername/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer/6.10.4/*
```

This is the source of the Hooks.java class:

```
package com.barrabes.fromaura.steps.endToEnd;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionId;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.barrabes.fromaura.utilities.TestContext;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
import io.qameta.allure.Allure;

public class Hooks {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Hooks.class);

    protected TestContext testContext;

    protected WebDriver webDriver;



    public Hooks() {
        TestContext context = new TestContext();
        this.testContext = context;
    }
/*
    public Hooks(TestContext context) {
        testContext = context;
    }


 */
    @Before
    public synchronized void setUp(Scenario scenario) {

        List<String> tags = (ArrayList<String>) scenario.getSourceTagNames();
        logger.info("Setting up "+scenario.getName()+tags.toString());   
        if (webDriver==null) {
            webDriver = testContext.getDriverManager().getDriver();     
            if (webDriver == null) {
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
    }
    
    
    @After
    public synchronized void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
        List<String> tags = (ArrayList<String>) scenario.getSourceTagNames();
        logger.info("Tear down "+scenario.getName()+tags.toString());     
        
        if (webDriver != null) {
            SessionId sessionId = ((RemoteWebDriver) webDriver).getSessionId();
            if (sessionId != null && scenario.isFailed()) {
                logger.info("Taking screenshot for failed scenario");
                Allure.addAttachment("Error screenshot",
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(((TakesScreenshot) webDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES)));
            }
            if (sessionId != null && webDriver != null) {
                webDriver.close();
                webDriver.quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just in case, my pom.xml looks like this:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.barrabes</groupId>
    <artifactId>liveconnect.auto.tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <cucumber.version>7.8.1</cucumber.version>
        <testng.version>7.4.0</testng.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.36</slf4j.version>
        <allure.version>2.17.2</allure.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-cucumber6-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                            <value>4</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

```
Could you give a hand with this issue?
The goal is to be able to initialize Hooks class and get test cases executed again.
Thanks for your attention.
````